# Imported font and Highcharts JS export

Tags: highcharts, google-webfonts

Is it possible to export an imported font
( like Google webfonts or an own .ttf fontface ) with Highcharts?

As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/764pP/)

if you try to export it uses a standard font.

```
title: {
   style: { 
      color: '#000',
      fontFamily : 'Patrick Hand SC'
          }
       }
```

I have also tried it with a local .ttf fontface but I cannot change the export font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should understand why it doesn't work.

If you use font on the website, browser is trying to find the font with a given name installed on your computer or imported with @font-face.

But when you export the chart Highcharts takes the SVG code, sends it to the server, server rasterizes SVG image into jpg, png or any format you asked for and sends it back to you.

The problem now is that your custom font is missing on the server, and you can't use @font-face here. Only way to do it, is to install font on the server, but since you're using default Highcharts exporting server, you can't install anything there.

What you can do is to set up your own exporting server and install the font that you need.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation! I thought it would be something like this but I wasn't sure! I'll try setting up my own export server then !

Comment: i'm not sure how accurate this is answer is, i am using a .NET solution with the relevant .dll files found here https://github.com/imclem/Highcharts-export-module-asp.net/blob/master/Exporting_Demo_website/Default.aspx - the problem still remains, even if i have the font installed on the same machine with the running website. It displays the right font on the screen, but not in the export. I would really like to see a working example of this.